# Access denied for user error during install phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-20.04

I want to install phpmyadmin on Ubuntu 20.04. I take the password 2 times (first I tryed root password but after I tryed leave the field empty or use other password). Any time I error like [screen of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ8hv.png). I found this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-20-04).
Author of this article wrote:

> From the prompt, run the following command to disable the Validate
>   Password component. Note that this won’t actually uninstall it, but
>   just stop the component from being loaded on your MySQL server:

But this component is disable and yet I still have this error. How can I solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

The error message you posted is different from the Validate Password one in the tutorial. I suggest re-enabling the option that you disabled.

Your error is showing that you (or someone) has changed the password of the MySQL user that Ubuntu (and Debian) uses for administrative purposes (debian-sys-maint). Details of that user are documented in `README.Debian` and the password is stored on disk in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`.

To resolve this, you can simply set the password to a known value and edit the configuration file to tell your system the new password.

[Presumably](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/mysql-server), you're using MySQL 8.0.20, in which case you would connect through the command line client (`mysql -u root -p`) and run a command like this: `ALTER USER 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'aReallyComplexPassword';`.

On the chance that you're using MariaDB, the command is `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('aReallyComplexPassword');`.

You won't need the password again after you put it in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf). Note that you'll need to edit the debian.cnf file as root or sudo.